# How to locate the verbatim text in centre of the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim

Here is an code that i want to display in verbatim mode.

But the displayed code  is locate at the left of the page.

```
 \begin{singlespace}
  \begin{verbatim}
 Imread('filename');
 \end{verbatim}
 \end{singlespace}
```

How too locate it in the centre of the page?

Answer (score 6):

Use `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\newenvironment{CVerbatim}
 {\singlespacing\center\BVerbatim}
 {\endBVerbatim\endcenter}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{CVerbatim}[fontsize=\small]
This is \verbatim text
which you will find centered on the page
\end{CVerbatim}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

The option `fontsize=\small` is just to show that you can pass `CVerbatim` any `fancyvrb` option.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Stuff the verbatim in a box first.  The optional argument allows you to "condition" the verbatim text, as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\textheight=1cm
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\tiny]
This is \verbatim text
which you will find centered on the page
\end{verbbox}
\centering\theverbbox
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  I presume you meant horizontally centered.