# How can a verbatim environment be centered using a basic LaTeX installation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim, code

I want to centre some verbatim text in a reasonable way using only a basic LaTeX installation, i.e. the packages `listings` and `fancyvrb` are not available.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
hello world
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{verbatim}
def main():
    print("hello world")
\end{verbatim}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How could the verbatim text be centered?

Comment: Related/duplicate?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/center-verbatim-text-in-figure or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130786/how-to-locate-the-verbatim-text-in-centre-of-the-page

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to use any additional code (why not?, I'd use `varwidth` here) then you can just use a normal `minipage` but you would have to tell it how many characters are on the longest line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
hello world
\end{center}

\begin{center}\ttfamily\sbox{0}{a}%
\begin{minipage}{24\wd0}% 24 characters here
\begin{verbatim}
def main():
    print("hello world")
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Package `varwidth` would help, because it can shorten the lines (that would use the full `\linewidth` otherwise):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
hello world
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
def main():
    print("hello world")
\end{verbatim}
\end{varwidth}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the package cannot be uses via `\usepackage`, its contents could be included
instead:

```
\makeatletter
... <contents of varwidth.sty without the initial \ProvidesPackage>
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\narrowragged{\rightskip \z@ plus .25\hsize 
  \@rightskip\rightskip \parfillskip\z@ plus .15\hsize
  \sloppy }

\newbox\@vwid@box
...
...
...
\@ifundefined{newcolumntype}{}{%
 \@ifundefined{NC@rewrite@V}{
 \newcolumntype{V}[1]{%
   >{\begin{varwidth}[t]{#1}\narrowragged\let\\\tabularnewline}%
   l%
   <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\end{varwidth}}}
 }{}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment lines with `%` at the start don't need to be copied, just the
code lines are important. Luckily the package does not use options (v0.92),
only `\ProvidesPackage` does not work outside correctly and needs to be
omitted.